# How to remotely read list item permissions in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: 2007, permissions

I have a console application which needs to read list item permissions from lists in a Sharepoint 2007 farm. I just need to read permissions, not change them. The console application does run remotely, so it needs to access the item permissions from outside the farm. Also, I cannot install anything on the 2007 farm.

As it turns out, the client object model was introduced with Sharepoint 2010, so I can't use that for Sharepoint 2007. Another possible option was the Lists.asmx service, but this service can only read permissions down to the list level, but not the list item level. Is there maybe another service for item permissions? What are possible solutions to this task? How can I get the list items permissions?

Comment: Uh, the SharePoint Object Model is available even in 2007 if you have a reference in your Visual Studio project to Microsoft.SharePoint.dll, just the same as in 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The out-of-the-box web services in SharePoint 2007 do not allow for permissions retrieval of anything other than a site or a list.

For individual listitem permissions, you need to create your own solution. That being said, you can find an example of a web service (for deployment to a SharePoint 2007 farm) that allows for retrieval of individual item permissions

http://www.codefornuts.com/2009/05/item-level-security-with-sharepoint-web.html

As you cannot install anything on sharepoint farm, so it would not be possible for you to read the item level permissions.